# How do I query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS on Amazon RDS?

Tags: errors, information-schema, redshift, system-tables, catalogs

I received a list of column names from another team. To ensure all field column names are valid inside a specific schema, I put them into a temporary table. I'm now wanting to see if they exist. When I try to join with `information_schema.columns`, I received errors below:

```
ERROR: 0A000: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
Column "c.column_name" has unsupported type     "information_schema.sql_identifier".
Column "a.*" has unsupported type "pg_attribute".
Column "t.*" has unsupported type "pg_type".
Function "format_type(oid,integer)" not supported.
Function "format_type(oid,integer)" not supported.
Function "has_table_privilege(oid,text)" not supported.
Function "has_table_privilege(oid,text)" not supported.
Function "has_table_privilege(oid,text)" not supported.
Function "has_table_privilege(oid,text)" not supported.
```

I tried to cast `column_name` into different types, but had no luck. Would anyone please advise what's wrong and how I can achieve this goal?

Comment: You're defining column name validity by not being anywhere in your schema?

Comment: Yes, to avoid typo.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I understand what's going on here so I cut out the information that I thought was unnecessary since I believe this is otherwise a really good question and likely to be pretty hot.

Comment: @lee you should update your question title to "How do I query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS on Amazon Redshift?" - Note that RDS <> Redshift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `PG_TABLE_DEF`

Amazon considers the internal functions that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is using [Leader-Node Only functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_functions_leader_node_only.html). Rather than being sensible and redefining the standardized `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, Amazon sought to define their own proprietary version. For that [they made available another function `PG_TABLE_DEF` which seems to address the same need.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html) Pay attention to the note in the center about adding the schema to `search_path`.

> Stores information about table columns.
>
> `PG_TABLE_DEF` only returns information about tables that are visible to the user. If `PG_TABLE_DEF` does not return the expected results, verify that the search_path parameter is set correctly to include the relevant schemas.
>
> You can use [`SVV_TABLE_INFO`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_TABLE_INFO.html) to view more comprehensive information about a table, including data distribution skew, key distribution skew, table size, and statistics.

So using your example code (rewritten to use `NOT EXISTS` for clarity),

```
SET SEARCH_PATH to '$user', 'public', 'target_schema';

SELECT "column" 
FROM dev.fields f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM PG_TABLE_DEF pgtd
  WHERE pgtd.column = f.field
  AND schemaname = 'target_schema'
);
```

See also,

- Official docs on [*Querying Redshift System Tables*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_querying_redshift_system_tables.html)

Comment: Evan, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and that really works for me! On a side note, why do you think NOT EXISTS is better than LEFT JOIN? I worked most with mssql and oracle where "NOT" is generally hated, so am trying to appreciate this change.

Comment: @Lee I think you're confusing NOT IN with NOT EXISTS. People tend to avoid NOT IN because it behaves in unexpected ways when NULLs are present.

Comment: @Lee `NOT EXISTS` is more explicit semantically and the binding is closer. That `WHERE col IS NULL` will work its way quite a bit when you add in a lot of `JOINS`. That means you have to maintain two discrete parts of your query to get the same functionality.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, you are so right. I typed NOT EXISTS but was actually thinking of NOT IN.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, thanks again for your great explanation.

Comment: @Lee see this for more information https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/195447/2639